# Access 2nd MySQL db in PHP without mysql_select_db()

Tags: php, mysql

If I select a db `db1` with `mysql_select_db()` is it possible to access another db `db2` in a query?  I am looking for something like `SELECT * FROM`db2.sometable`WHERE 1`

Answer (score 1):

That syntax should work perfectly fine.  If you want to access a table from another database the syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.TableName WHERE ....
```

However, this only works if both databases are on the same instance of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes - have you tried it? and do you have access privileges to the 2nd db?

Answer (score 0):

its possible just reference the db name in your query like `select * from db.table`